# Is the Unseen University's librarian trying to say 'book'?

Tags: discworld

Early on in the series the librarian at the Unseen University is transformed into an orangutan (**not** a monkey).

From then on, they only say "Ook" with various inflections and changes in length. This is obviously an 'ape vocalisation' but Pratchett is known for his clever plays on words, and I wouldn't put it past him to have chose the orangutan based on the 'book'/'ook' similarity.

So is this an attempt to say "book" and a clever play on words by Pratchett or *just* ape vocalisation?

Comment: I've found no statements from Pratchett so far. Unless we find one, it may just be conjecture.

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/q/496303 It's a stereotypical monkey sound.

Comment: @OrganicMarble of course it it, it wouldn't be a play on words otherwise. It's what I called 'ape vocalisation'.

Comment: *"Ook." "I don't know what I'll say to him. "Don't blow the world up" sounds a pretty persuasive argument to me. I'd listen to it. And I don't like the idea of going anywhere near the gods. We're like toys to them, you know." And they don't realise how easily the arms and legs come off, he added to himself. "Ook?" "Pardon? Do you really say that?" "Ook." "There is a... monkey god?" "Ook?" "No, no, that's fine, fine. Not one of our locals ones, is he?" "Eek."*  - The Last Hero

Comment: I don't really understand this question. Are you asking if Ook actually means things, or why Pratchett had the Librarian make [the same sound as a real orangutan](https://youtu.be/PB5gKiVEzZs?t=53)?

Comment: Um, no?  As in neither is correct?  I don't have any reference materials handy, but I remember monkeys/apes saying "ook" in comic strips dating back to the 1930s.

Comment: @OrganicMarble You're playing with fire there - are you sure the Librarian can't come through the L-space and get very angry with you?

Comment: This question now seems even more unclear. Are you asking if Pratchett chose to have the librarian be an orangutan because orangutans say "ook" and that sounds a bit like "book"?

Comment: "ook" doesn't even *rhyme* with book. It's just a joke that all he can say is the sterotypical monkey sounds "ook" and "eek" but their meaning changes. Real librarians don't go around saying "book, book, book". Stereotypically they say "ssssh".

Comment: The Irony would be that Apes do not have lips and thus cannot vocalize a labial phoneme as /b/. That would make it a very grimm word play on the disability of the librarian. No passage to stress the Librarian wanted to, but couldn't, say "book" is coming to mind.

Answer (score 11):

At https://discworld.fandom.com/wiki/The_Librarian
I found this,

> He speaks an elaborate language whose vocabulary consists of the single word Ook (and its antonym "eek" - where "ook" means yes, "eek" tends to mean no). Nonetheless, most people seem to be able to understand him.

The implication being that, similar to “I am Groot”, “Ook” can mean basically anything. However, there is no mention of the source for this, Pratchett or otherwise and it’s been a while since I read the books personally.